# How can I find out which rows in my table have a column with a length > 50?

Tags: sql-server, string-length

I have a table and the column [English] I think has some values with a length of > 50. I want to insert this into another table where the max length is 50.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[jlpt$] 
(
    [kanji]   NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [kana]    NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [english] NVARCHAR (255) NULL
);
```

How can I find these rows and also is there a way I can truncate the value of `[English]` to 50 so the column contents will fit into a column with a (50) length?

Answer (score 6):

To show rows that have length of `[english]` column which is greater than 50:

```
select *
from [dbo].[jlpt$]
where len([english]) > 50
```

To truncate those exceeding your length limit to first 50 characters:

```
update [dbo].[jlpt$]
set keyword = left([english], 50)
where len([english]) > 50
```

To insert values into different table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[anothertable]
  SELECT [kanji], [kana], left([english], 50)
  FROM [dbo].[jlpt$]
```

From manual

> [`LEFT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms177601(v=sql.110).aspx) Returns the left part of a character string with the specified number of characters.
>
> [`LEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms190329(v=sql.110).aspx) Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.

If your column contains trailing blanks, use [`DATALENGTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms173486(v=sql.110).aspx) function instead.

If you don't care about checking and playing with trailing spaces, just issue `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and everything is done.